# Abstract or Hide API Calls from Copycats

Tags: php, api, https, abstraction

We're building a system that utilizes certain third-party API that we'd like to keep "close to chest" due to the services reliance on these APIs.

At first we thought that we would create a communication layer and daisy-chain the requests from one website to another ... but then we considered coding an abstraction layer so that we wouldn't loose response time from hoping from site to site.

What is the best way to abstract / anonymize / hide calls to third party APIs so that we can protect our assets from the prying eyes of our competition? **Keep in mind that these calls eventually have to be made over HTTP(S) via REST, so I'm not sure that abstraction will ultimately work, since the endpoints of communication will be exposed...**

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you mean instead of making the calls from the client. In which case, I would have an API endpoint on your backend and then send the request to the third-party application from your backend system - rather than the frontend.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking as well. Now the complicated aspect is when this ends up turning into a WP plugin ... which installs all the source code. In that case, we'd absolutely need to create some sort of middleware.

Comment: If you really wanted to, the plugin would make requests to a separate application that you control. The request then goes to the third party service

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was thinking... I'd like to diagram this because I think it could be useful for others.